# How can I display the line position in a TextBox on the status bar?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, textbox, statusbar, statusstrip

I have added a `StatusStrip` control and placed a `StatusLabel` inside of it. But now I want to know how to connect it to my TextBox to show the line number and position of the cursor, like: "Line 2, Row 6".

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Get the index of the caret in the TextBox:

   **C#**

   ```
   int caretIndex = textBox.SelectionStart;
   ```

   **VB.NET**

   ```
   Dim caretIndex As Integer = textBox.SelectionStart
   ```
2. Get the line number from the caret index:

   **C#**

   ```
   int lineNumber = textBox.GetLineFromCharIndex(caretIndex);
   ```

   **VB.NET**

   ```
   Dim lineNumber As Integer = textBox.GetLineFromCharIndex(caretIndex)
   ```
3. Get the character index in the current line:

   **C#**

   ```
   Point characterXY = textBox.GetPositionFromCharIndex(caretIndex);
   int characterIndex = textBox.GetCharIndexFromPosition(characterXY);
   ```

   **VB.NET**

   ```
   Dim characterXY As Point = textBox.GetPositionFromCharIndex(caretIndex)
   Dim characterIndex As Integer = textBox.GetCharIndexFromPosition(characterXY)
   ```

---

I guess you can continue from here ...

Comment: He will also need `GetFirstCharIndexOfCurrentLine`