# Current key position in text box

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005, textbox

In winform's textbox, how to get the current key-in position?

For example -

textbox.text = 3056.98

If I type '7' after '0', current key-in position is 3.

In vb.net, which textbox event or keyword could I get this position value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a Winforms TextBox you can get the current cursor position with the `SelectionStart` property.

In WPF the same can be found using the `CaretIndex` property.

Not sure about ASP.NET - I doubt you can retrieve this server-side.

Answer (score 2):

1. Get the index of the caret in the TextBox:

   **C#**

   ```
   int caretIndex = textBox.SelectionStart;
   ```

   **VB.NET**

   ```
   Dim caretIndex As Integer = textBox.SelectionStart
   ```
2. Get the line number from the caret index:

   **C#**

   ```
   int lineNumber = textBox.GetLineFromCharIndex(caretIndex);
   ```

   **VB.NET**

   ```
   Dim lineNumber As Integer = textBox.GetLineFromCharIndex(caretIndex)
   ```
3. Get the character index in the current line:

   **C#**

   ```
   Point characterXY = textBox.GetPositionFromCharIndex(caretIndex);
   int characterIndex = textBox.GetCharIndexFromPosition(characterXY);
   ```

   **VB.NET**

   ```
   Dim characterXY As Point = textBox.GetPositionFromCharIndex(caretIndex)
   Dim characterIndex As Integer = textBox.GetCharIndexFromPosition(characterXY)
   ```

---

I guess you can continue from here ...

---

Refer to [How can I display the line position in a TextBox on the status bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5692714/how-can-i-display-the-line-position-in-a-textbox-on-the-status-bar/5692832#5692832)

Comment: Dear @AkramShahda, is this for multi-line text box? thank you.

Comment: @soclose: Yes indeed. However, you can use the first step to get the position in a single line TextBox.